# WiXでインストーラー作成時にエラーが出ます

Tags: windows

WiXを使用してインストーラーを作成しているのですが、規約の文章を挿入するとエラーが表示されインストーラーが作成できません。

```
C:\Users\(省略)\Installer>light -nologo untitled.obj -out untitled.msi -ext WixUIExtension
C:\agent\_work\66\s\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\LicenseAgreementDlg.wxs(27) : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file 'license.rtf'.
```

インストーラーのXMLファイル作成にはWiX Editを使用しており、該当部分の書き換えはしていません。

インストーラーの作成方法については以下のページを参考にしました

[WiXを使って無料でインストーラーを作る！ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/Yanase-Takuma/items/bf0a360c9d37ca03a272)

Comment: "license.rtf が見つからない" とエラーに出ているので、ファイル名または保存場所が間違っていないか辺りをまず確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 確認しました。ファイルパスを変更しても同じエラーが出ます